# What is difference between testing in context of CI and CT pipelines?

Tags: continuous-integration

What is the difference between testing in the context of Continuous Integration pipeline vs testing in context of Continuous Testing pipeline? The definition of testing is a bit blurred to me in the context of CT pipeline.

An example, I understand testing in CI where a Unit Test is executed on a Pull Request - personally I'd defined it as a Continuous Testing since I continuously test incoming code however, this practice is known as CI. Then, what is CT then? Am I only one confusing CI for CT?

Answer (score 2):

Continuous Testing is a [side effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_integration) of Continuous Integration. CI's main purpose is to integrate your development efforts into a production-ready state as often as possible. The production-readiness is granted via continuously testing the recently integrated code. Continuous Integration does not work properly without Continuous Testing, but you could continuously test without making your development code production ready all the time. In my experience the CT term is not really in use anymore.